# Kubernetes on GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I am trying to setup Kubernetes on GCE. My question is ,  lets say there are 20 minions part of the cluster in Kubernetes, and two services deployed with type LoadBalancer with replicas as 2 each. So K8S will basically put 2 pods on two different minions per service. My question is, would the rest of the minions which are not running any pods also get the iptables rule in chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER and KUBE-PORTALS-HOST  for these two services added? At least that is my observation but would like to confirm if this is just how Kubernetes works on GCE or this is how K8S behaves irrespective of where it is deployed. Is the reason that any service should be reachable from any minion no matter whether the minion is part of that service or not ? Let me know if there is a better community for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

> Would the rest of the minions which are not running any pods also get the iptables rule in chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER and KUBE-PORTALS-HOST for these two services added?

Yes. The load balancer can forward external traffic to any node in the cluster, so every node needs to be able to receive traffic for a service and forward it to the appropriate pod.

> I would like to confirm if this is just how Kubernetes works on GCE or this is how K8S behaves irrespective of where it is deployed.

The iptables rule for services *within* the cluster is the same regardless of where Kubernetes is deployed. Making a service externally accessible differs slightly depending on where you deploy your cluster (e.g. on AWS you'd create the service as type NodePort instead of type LoadBalancer), so the iptables rule for services that are externalized can vary a bit.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I am slightly confused about this. Agreed if the load balancer is programmed to forward traffic to any of the nodes in a Kubernetes cluster, than it makes sense that any node in K8S cluster should be able to forward traffic  for any service running in the cluster. But in a slightly better world, if my loadbalancer forwards traffic to nodes running at least one pods, this seems like extra hops. I understand building that kind of load balancer would be duplicating some of what kube-proxy already does. Is there config to control if iptables rule go on node with that pod running ?

Comment: Yes, this configuration can sometimes lead to extra hops. AFAIK there isn't any way to control the iptables rules to reduce the extra hops.